# How to filter our a specific email using Regularexpression validator

Tags: asp.net

I'm writing a program which has a email field. I want to put a restriction that only `username@gmail.com` emails would be valid. But when I try to run, my RegularExpression Validator gives me a mistake

This is the code I'm using:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="ExistMail" runat="server" ></asp:TextBox><font size='2'>
      <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator3" class="errorMess" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Invalid Email Address!!!" ControlToValidate="ExistMail"

      <ValidationExpression="\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+gmail.com\w+)*"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```

Comment: You mean only username@gmail.com is allowed to enter?

Comment: yes only gmail user are allowed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove \w+ after of @ and \w+ in the end of string

```
\w+([-+.']\w+)*@gmail.com
```